# Creating data.frames where one column contains matrices

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I would like to create a list column of matrices, where the entries of each matrix are elements from variables already present in the original dataset. My goal is to create 2 time 2 contingency tables for each row of the data set, and subsequently pass each matrix as an argument to `fisher.test`.

I have tried adding the new column using a combination of `mutate` and `matrix`, but this returns an error. I've also tried using `do` instead of `mutate` and this seems like a step in the right direction, but I know this is also incorrect, because the dimensions of the elements are off, and there is only one row in the output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mat = matrix(c(.$disp, .$hp, .$gear, .$carb)))
#> Error: Column `mat` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 128

mtcars %>% 
  do(mat = matrix(c(.$disp, .$hp, .$gear, .$carb)))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   mat            
#>   <list>         
#> 1 <dbl [128 x 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I am expecting 32 rows in my output, and the `mat` column to contain 32 2x2 matrices composed of entries from `mtcars$disp`, `mtcars$hp`, `mtcars$gear`, and `mtcars$carb`.

My intent is to use `map` to pass each entry in the `mat` column as an argument to `fisher.test`, then extract the odds ratio estimate, and the p-value. But the main focus, of course, is creation of the list of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

- To store a matrix in a data.frame (tibble), you simply have to put it in a list.
- To create 2 x 2 matrices (instead of repeating the same 4 x 32 matrix in each cell), you need to work row by row. Currently, when you do `matrix(c(disp, hp, gear, carb))` you create a 4 x 32 matrix! You want only 4 x 1 inputs, reshaped to 2 x 2.

Working with `pmap` allows you to process the rows one by one, but alternatively you can use `rowwise` which groups by row:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- 
  mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble() %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(mat = list(matrix(c(disp, hp, gear, carb), 2, 2)))
```

Edit: Now how do you actually use those? Let's take the example of a `fisher.test`. Note that a test is a complex object, with components (like p.value) and attributes, so we'll have to store them in a list-column.

You can either keep working `rowwise`, in which case the list is automagically "unlist-ed":

```r
df %>%
  # keep in mind df is still grouped by row so 'mat' is only one matrix.
  # A test is a complex object so we need to store it in a list-column
  mutate(test = list(fisher.test(mat)), 
         # test is just one test so we can extract p-value directly 
         pval = test$p.value)
```

Or if you stop working row by row (for which you simply need to `ungroup`), then `mat` is a list of matrices onto which you can map functions. We use the `map` functions from `purrr`.

```r
library("purrr")

df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Apply the test to each mat using `map` from `purrr` 
  # `map` returns a list so `test` is a list-column
  mutate(test = map(mat, fisher.test), 
         # Now `test` is a list of tests... so you need to map operations onto it 
         # Extract the p-values from each test, into a numeric column rather than a list-column
         pval = map_dbl(test, pluck, "p.value"))
```

Which one you prefer is a matter of taste :)

Comment: This is very easy to read and interpret. Do you have any recommendations on how to pass the elements of `mat` into functions that take a matrix as input, such as `fisher.test`? I have tried using `map_at(., "mat", fisher.test)` and get the  following error which leads me to believe the elements are being extracted as a  numeric vector instead of a matrix: #> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...): if 'x' is not a matrix, 'y' must be given

Comment: @ChrisAguilar: Sure, I edited it in. When you do `map_at` on your data.frame, you simply apply `fisher.test` on `df$mat` which is a list of matrices, not a matrix. You would need to do `map_at(., "mat", ~ map(., fisher.test))` which is exactly equivalent to `mutate(., mat = map(mat, fisher.test))`. See my edit for more details!

Comment: Your explanation is outstanding. I appreciate the assistance. Do you have any recommendations on readings/references to learn more about programming with R in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `pmap` function from the `purrr` package inside `mutate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(mat = pmap(list(disp, hp, gear, carb), ~matrix(c(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4), 2, 2)))

# A tibble: 32 x 12
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb mat              
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>           
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 <dbl[,2] [2 x 2]>
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 <dbl[,2] [2 x 2]>
```

Each entry of mat is then a 2x2 matrix with the desired elements. Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution to the primary problem posed works perfectly. I am now trying to pass the elements of `mat` into `fisher.test`, and I figured it would be a simple `map_at` call, but it doesn't seem to be quite so straightfoward, and I appreciate any further assistance with this matter:


mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(mat = pmap(list(disp, hp, gear, carb), 
               ~matrix(c(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4), 2, 2))) %>%
  map_at(., "mat", fisher.test)
#> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...): if 'x' is not a matrix, 'y' must be given